# Chrome extension to block url on specific website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I block urls on specific website using chrome extension:
I have written small extension to block URLs. But I want it to block those URLs only on specific website.
**manifest.json**

```js
{
  "name": "vidstreamBlocker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Chrome URL Blocking Extension",
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>","activeTab"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  info => {
    const host = (info.initiator || '').split('/', 3)[2];
    if (host === 'example.com') {
      return {cancel: true};
    }
  },
  
  {urls: 
    ["*://*.ad-delivery.net/*"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

I know background.js runs continuously but I want to block them on specific website only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `initiator` property ([more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest)):

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  info => {
    const host = (info.initiator || '').split('/', 3)[2];
    if (host === 'www.example.com') {
      return {cancel: true};
    }
  },
  {
    urls: [
      '*://*.eikegolehem.com/*',
      '*://*.inpagepush.com/*',
    ],
  },
  ['blocking']
);
```

P.S. You can replace `<all_urls>` in manifest.json with the patterns for the main site and the resources.

Comment: replacing <all_urls> don't work same goes for the solution you gave it is not working. The extension stop blocking

Comment: Without seeing what exactly you did I guess you did it incorrectly.

Comment: I have editrd the code above in question with the changes

Comment: You need to list the URLs of all resources you want to block in permissions, too.

Comment: Thanks it worked. but it is only working till the page is loading once it's loaded it stop blocking

Comment: webRequest blocks anything regardless of whether the page is loading or has already loaded so the only explanation is that the page is doing something different. Maybe it uses an iframe to load those resources. You need to investigate what's happening by examining the requests in devtools and figuring out the difference. No one else can do it.

Comment: You are right the page is using iframe. inside I frame the URL is being loaded. so host keep changing if i add all blocked url in host then it will work on other websites too. I tried getting to limit it this website. but I am not able to

Comment: Does the iframe have something unique in its URL, which you could use in `initiator` check?

Comment: Yes I did it. i used iframe url and it started working- Thanks a lot